# Internal server error Ajax get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I've got a problem. For my project Im using php laravel and bootstrap for css. Jquery to get some information into my bootstrap modal. It works fine I've got my script file imported and it works. I have this setup in my index page. now I needed to do the exact same thing on my employeedetail page and I get a 500 internal server error.

Can someone help me out?

script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".aanvullen").click(function(){
request = $.ajax({
        url: "modalData",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
                "id": this.name
              }
    });

   request.done(function (res, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if (res.status = "ok"){     
        console.log(res);
        $("#addDossier").modal('show');
       }
   }); });   });
```

The same code is working perfectly fine in my index js file.

Hope someone can tell me what the problem might be

It says the request = $.ajax is a anonymous function. As far as I know this has the same imported files as the other where it does work.

Comment: I fixed it, always doubting to ask stackoverflow and than 5 min after my question I solve it! haha anyways: it was the route problem from index the route was modalData, from employeedetail the route was ../modalData

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was a route problem from index the route was modalData, from employeedetail the route was ../modalData